# Enumerable LINQ extensions are hidden on strings... why and how?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq, string, .net-3.5, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t VS 2008 display extension methods in Intellisense for String class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345883/why-doesnt-vs-2008-display-extension-methods-in-intellisense-for-string-class)

Hi all.

Yesterday I noticed that `Enumerable` LINQ exstensions are hidden on strings (I mean hidden from the intellisense).

We all know string is an `IEnumerable<char>`, so automatically it should get Enumerable extensions, and actually compiles and works if you use them, but why .NET developers decided to hide them from intellisense?

And lastly, how we can hide extension methods from a specific type ?

P.S.
sorry for my poor english...

EDIT:
I forgot to say I'm targeting .net 3.5 on VS 2008

EDIT2:
Here 2 images of what happen:

**Intellisense on string:**

[Intellisense on string http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/10/stringintelli.png](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/10/stringintelli.png)

**Intellisense on IEnumerable:**

[image: Intellisense on enumerable]

Comment: Do you have System.Core referenced as an assembly?

Comment: I don't know why it's hidden, but I can verify that the extension methods are hidden for strings in VS 2008, but not in VS 2010.

Comment: see also this Usenet thread scrape: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32196968/vs2008-intellisense-hidin.aspx (some familiar names in there...)

Comment: also note that with VS2008 plus ReSharper 5, you *do* get them shown.

Comment: ...and sorry for the duplication but I was not able to find a similar question even if I searched it before posting (I voted to close).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have a string `s` and type `s.` I do get all the extensions methods (like FirstOrDefault etc).

I checked with VS2010 Express.

You should of course have the `static class System.Linq.Enumerable` in scope.

---

As for the How part, I guess that something like [this attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute%28VS.80%29.aspx) was used on String. But clearing the "Hide advanced" option for C# brought no change, so it is not exactly this attribute but something similar.

As for the Why part, no idea. But interesting that it was changed for Fx4

Comment: Sorry I edited my question, I'm using VS2008

Comment: OK, verified. In VS2008 the methods _don't_ show up in intellisense .

Comment: Oh well, so it's not only me :) . Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Not on my copy of Visual Studio (that's 2010, with ReSharper installed):

[alt text http://codeka.com/tmp/string-enumerable.png](http://codeka.com/tmp/string-enumerable.png)

Perhaps you forgot the `using System.Linq;` at the top? Or maybe ReSharper is adding them, not sure...

Comment: I edited my question. I'm using VS2008 and I have "using System.Linq" at the top.