# Store list of directory as an Array vb2008

Tags: vb.net

How will I store list of directories into an array? I've tried this method but this doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim parentinfo As New DirectoryInfo("C:\myfiles")

    counter1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\myfiles")
    dirsize = counter1.Count

    ReDim directory(dirsize)

    For Each dir As FileSystemInfo In parentinfo.GetFileSystemInfos()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        directory(i) = dir.Name
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(directory(i))
        i += 1
    Next dir

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see you declaring `directory()` anywhere... Is it global?

Comment: Are you getting any errors(compiletime/runtime) with your code.?

Comment: nope.. there are no errors at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
Public Sub New()

    Dim directories As New List(Of DirectoryInfo)

    Call Me.InitializeComponent()

    Call Me.ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each directory As DirectoryInfo In (New DirectoryInfo("C:\")).GetDirectories()
        Call directories.Add(directory)
        Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(directory.Name)
    Next

End Sub
```

This will generate a list `directories` of `DirectoryInfo` objects for all directories found in the specified path. It will also add all directory names to the combobox (in this case `Combobox1`.

UPDATE

Just realised that you asked for an array specifically. You can transform a list to array by using the `ToArray()` extension method. So in this case at the end of the sub you can just call `directories.ToArray()` to get your array. Alternatively you can use the code I wrote with an array, but frankly, why use an array if you can use a list?

If you want to do it with an array here is the code:

```
Public Sub New()

    Dim i as integer

    Call Me.InitializeComponent()

    ReDim directory(i)
    For Each dir As DirectoryInfo In (New DirectoryInfo("C:\")).GetDirectories()
        directory(i) = dir
        Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(directory.Name)
        i += 1
        ReDim Preserve directory(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

But I think it's a pain in the backside to do it this way...

Comment: how will i declare directory? it gives an error when defined as Dim directory As New List(Of DirectoryInfo)

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Since you have defined directory globally as well, try giving the local variable a different name, or define the global variable as a List instead of an array.

Comment: i followed my pattern to read directories.. but this help me a lot to understand array.

Comment: thanks yu_ominae..it is ok now. though i have to remove Call Me. InitializeComponent..doesn't work in mine when calling combobx.  =)

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's a left-over from the form I used to test your code. I put mine in the `New()` sub, which then requires the `InitializeComponent()` call. By the way, be careful when you use the `Load` event to do stuff, because it has a bug which makes it swallow exceptions (see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209706/why-the-form-load-cant-catch-exception).