# Program ignores everything after opening new SQL connection

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

In my program I open a new SQL connection like so:

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString);
con.Open();
```

I can't quite work out when it stopped working, but now, whenever I debug, the program ignores everything past the first line. For example, if I put a breakpoint on "con.Open();" then the breakpoint is not processed - the form is shown as if nothing has happened.

However, if I have a button on the form, it will fire any of those events without hassle.

If more details are required, let me know, and thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you accidentally disabled debugging?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? I wonder if it could be timing out or just sitting trying to connect with an incorrect connection string.

Comment: is the breakpoint solid, or is it hollow?

Comment: Are these line wrapped inside a try/catch clause?

Comment: @shadowjfaith No errors whatsoever, and  should have mentioned that if I put a breakpoint of the first line then it still breaks at that point. Just nowhere after it. 
And I have tried moving the first line to various different points and always the same effect - breaks at that line but nowehere after it.

Comment: @christiandev Nope, all solid

Comment: @SystemDown No, they are in a method called by the Form Load event. But, as I say, there is other code both before and after these lines within the method. The code before runs fine, but the code after is ignored.

Comment: are other breakpoints being hit? can you post more of the code around these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an exception, but the Load event is eating it.

Try moving your code to the Shown event instead to see the exception.

See [Why the form load can't catch exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3209706/719186)

See [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a WinForms Application on a 64-bit version of Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4934010/719186)

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but what exactly do you mean about "moving [my] code to the Shown event"?

Comment: @NerdJam In stead of the Load event, use the Shown event, and move the code that you have in the Load event to the Shown event method.  There is a bug in WinForms where exceptions get swallowed in the Load event.  You should rarely use the Load event anyway.

Comment: Aha, yeah, gotcha, just needed it rephrased a bit. Worked great, thank you! (The problem was I had a semi-colon in my DB password)