# Load xml and get xml node value

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

Hi I have a xml in my Windows forms application. I am tring to get a node value. It is pretty basic and a lot of ways to get it I know but the wuestion is my xml not even loading. When I debug, after this line

```
xml.LoadXml(xmlPath);
```

program refuses to go to next line at all.Here is my full code.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
string xmlPath = "settings.xml";
xml.LoadXml(xmlPath);
txtPass.Text = xml.SelectSingleNode("settings/user-settings/pass").InnerText.ToString();
```

Edit : I also tried xml.Load() but I have the same issue.

Comment: Well when you debug you go next line with f10 or f11 right? It is not going to next line at all. It fires the application form to screen.

Comment: Maybe the file is in use by another program exclusively?

Comment: No it is not I checked.

Comment: Copy and paste that example into other project (console app) and check if it runs properly.

Comment: When it "doesn't go to next line" it throws an exception and defaults to the UI thread, which is why the form is shown. If you were to put the load xml line in a try/catch block, you'd see it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xml file name is  "CompSpecs"

```
{
                        string path = @"";
                        FileStream READER = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite); //Set up the filestream (READER) //
                        System.Xml.XmlDocument CompSpecs = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();// Set up the XmlDocument (CompSpecs) //
                        CompSpecs.Load(READER); //Load the data from the file into the XmlDocument (CompSpecs) //
                        System.Xml.XmlNodeList NodeList = CompSpecs.GetElementsByTagName("CompSpecs"); 
                        textBox1.Text = NodeList[0].FirstChild.NextSibling.ChildNodes[0].InnerText; 
}
```

My XML FILE IS

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <CompSpecs>
- <CP>
  <Type>intel Hp Core2DU</Type> 
  <RAM>4GBszz</RAM> 
  <CPU_Speed>3.8Ghz</CPU_Speed> 
  </CP>
- <CP>
  <Type>intel dell</Type> 
  <RAM>4GB</RAM> 
  <CPU_Speed>3.8Ghz</CPU_Speed> 
  </CP>
  </CompSpecs>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `LoadXml` is not meant to load files but XML content.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @MCanSener that's probably for a different reason (most likely can't find the file)

Comment: Well at last it should fire an exception or goes to next line as null isn't it?

Comment: @MCanSener http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209706/why-the-form-load-cant-catch-exception