# Cant load image in context menu as icon

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu, toolstripmenu, toolstripdropdown

I am trying to use the code from the following link:

[**VB- Helper** Create menu items at run time with images, shortcut keys, and event handlers in Visual Basic .NET](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_runtime_menus.html)

The only difference is that I want a local image and not one from my.Recources

What I have is the following:

```
    ''Tool 2 displays a string and image.
    Dim tool2 As New ToolStripMenuItem("Tool 2", (Image.FromFile("C:\test\icon.jpg")))
    tool2.Name = "mnuToolsTool2"
    tool2.ShortcutKeys = (Keys.D2 Or Keys.Control) ' Ctrl+2
    AddHandler tool2.Click, AddressOf mnuTool2_Click
    ToolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add(tool2)
```

Comment: Are you using a ContextMenuStrip control?

Comment: Its Work Correctly what kind of error is you get?

Comment: It works fine, check your file location maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce this "error". However, from the given text, code and link, my best guess is as follows:

1. You are using a 64 bit machine.
2. You run the code inside the `Form.Load` event.
3. An error occurs somewhere in this method.

```
Private Sub _Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Code...
    Throw New Exception("ooops..")
    'Code...
End Sub
```

As you might *not* know is that errors thrown in the `Form.Load` on a 64 bit machine are "swallowed" by the system.

For more information, read this SO post: [Why the form load can't catch exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209706/why-the-form-load-cant-catch-exception)

You should move your code inside the constructor:

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.InitializeComponent()
    'Code goes here...
End Sub
```

Or change to the `Form.Shown` event:

```
Private Sub _Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    Try
        'Code goes here...
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```