# Unable to access text or value of datetime picker of tabpage2 on tabpage1

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have windows form containing tab control, having two tab pages

[image]

on form load event i passed value to datetimpicker1 exists on tab page 2

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      dateTimePicker1.Text = "2014-05-14 00:00:00.000";    
    }
```

and on check button click event i have following code

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString());
    }
```

output:

[image]

2)on navigating to tabpage2 & then click on check button

[image]

output:

[image]

& then after come back to tabpage1 & click on check it shows correct output

[image]

why it not showing at first time as we open form & clcik on check button without going to tab page 2

Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: having same code only on Value Changed event 

i have following code

 private void Display_Date(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTimePicker dt = (DateTimePicker)sender;                     //Display Date on Select
            dt.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dt.CustomFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
        }

i.e display date in custom format

Comment: Move all code in Load event into Shown event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209706/why-the-form-load-cant-catch-exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Controls contained in a TabPage are not created until the tab page is shown, and any data bindings in these controls are not activated until the tab page is shown.

In form load you can select your tab as well.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
        dateTimePicker1.Text = "2014-05-14 00:00:00.000";            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Controls contained in a TabPage are not created until the tab page is shown, and any data bindings in these controls are not activated until the tab page is shown.

You can, for example, programmatically switch to `tabPage2` and back to the first tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString());
     }
```