# C# thread created and started in Form1_Load doesn't actually start

Tags: c#, multithreading

If i start a thread like this

```
addingResults = new Thread(threadAddingResults);
addingResults.Start();
```

In the Form1_Load function the thread doesn't start but if i start it with the same code on a lets say button click it works fine. Any reason why this is going on? Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: What does the thread do? It starts, but depending on what you have it do, the results are lost/not observed.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside Form1_Load and threadAddingResults to check with the debugger?

Comment: Where do you declare `addingResults`? if this is in the load event too then it will go out of scope very quickly

Comment: @Sayse Why does that matter?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - The OP doesn't state what they are trying to do but it is possible that the thread is ending before having chance to finish (I don't believe that it "doesn't actualy start")

Comment: @Sayse I can't understand your comment, what do you mean by *thread is ending before having chance to finish*?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Finishing early? Finishing before the expected behaviour of the thread is completed

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, i declared the thread as a variable outside and before i innitialized it i called **addingResults.IsBackground** for some reason no exception was returned in debug mode but the code after this in Form1_Load wasnt being executed.

So i just did this

```
addingResults = new Thread(threadAddingResults);
addingResults.IsBackground = true;
addingResults.Start();
```

And it works

Comment: Unfortunately exceptions in Form_Load are silently swallowed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209706/why-the-form-load-cant-catch-exception

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yep i know that now too