# vb.net why control doesn't return to original caller?

Tags: vb.net

I have made researched but none of them related to my question in VB.net.
I don't know why after calling to other subs, they don't return to the original caller in Form_Load()

In the form_load, I call this sub:

```
 Public Sub frm1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1       
         Call calculateCounts(dt.Rows(i).Item(0))     'call sub and pass the parameter

    Next
End Sub

Public Sub calculateCounts(ByVal st as string)
'In this sub, I calculate the counts for a 2D array and pass it to another sub     procedure
     DisplayData(aryRow, st)
End sub

Public DisplayData(ByRef aryRow(,) as integer, ByVal st as string)
     'This sub display data
End Sub
```

After it runs through the first time, display data correctly for the "st" parameter, it doesn't return to the original caller (form_load) to proceed to the next row. Do you know what is wrong here and what is the alternative way to fix it? thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: if `aryRow` is uninitilized - we cant see that it is - you could be encountering a NullReference exception.  Move your Form_load code to a button click and see what happens (diagnostic); maybe set a breakpoint to be sure it *isnt* returning

Comment: This is probably a mix of **[What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)** and **[Why the form load can't catch exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209706/why-the-form-load-cant-catch-exception)**.

Comment: Plutonix and Bjorn-Roger are correct. I have NullReference exception because I declare the aryRow(,) outside the loop without initializing it. Redim indise the loop and reuse outside it. Array trouble! I have to change to List (of Integer). It's new to me, though