# How many specified chars are in a string?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, string

taken a string example as `550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000` how can one **count how many** `-` chars are in such string?

I'm currently using:

```
int total = "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000".Split('-').Length + 1;
```

Is there any method that we don't need to add 1... like using the `Count` maybe?

All other methods such as

`Contains` `IndexOf` etc only return the first position and a `boolean` value, nothing returns **how many** were found.

what am I missing?

Comment: You need to subtract 1, not add it...

Comment: true :) my mistake writing the answer... correct on code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the LINQ method [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) for this purpose (note that a `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`):

```
int numberOfHyphens = text.Count(c => c == '-');
```

The argument is a `Func<char, bool>`, a predicate that specifies when an item is deemed to have 'passed' the filter.

This is (loosely speaking) equivalent to:

```
int numberOfHyphens = 0;

foreach (char c in text)
{
    if (c == '-') numberOfHyphens++;
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining that this is part of LINQ, and why it works for this.

Answer (score 5):

```
using System.Linq;

..

int total = "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000".Count(c => c == '-');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int total = "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000".Count(c => c == '-');
```

Answer (score 4):

The most straight forward method is to simply loop throught the characters, as that is what any algorithm has to do some way or the other:

```
int total = 0;
foreach (char c in theString) {
  if (c == '-') total++;
}
```

You can use extension methods to do basically the same:

```
int total = theString.Count(c => c == '-');
```

Or:

```
int total = theString.Aggregate(0, (t,c) => c == '-' ? t + 1 : t)
```

Then there are interresting (but less efficient) tricks like removing the characters and compare the lengths:

```
int total = theString.Length - theString.Replace("-", String.Empty).Length;
```

Or using a regular expression to find all occurances of the character:

```
int total = Regex.Matches(theString, "-").Count;
```

Comment: Now I wonder which of these variations have which benefits compared to each other and, if that matters, which one is faster or more efficient.

Comment: @Cthulhu: The simple loop is the most efficient, it's hard to improve on that. The `Count` version is resonably close in performance, and produces shorter code.

Answer (score 2):

```
int total = "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000".Count(c => c == '-')
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the number of '-' in a string, you are going to need to loop through the string and check each character, so the simplest thing to do is to just write a function that does that.  Using Split actually takes more time because it creates arrays for no reason.

Also, it's confusing what you are trying to do, and it even looks like you got it wrong (you need to subtract 1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string s = "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000";
int result = s.ToCharArray().Count( c => c == '-');
```

Comment: Why bother calling ToCharArray first?

Comment: I also noticed that intellisense doesn't offered my Count(this) for a string, it only worked then converting to a char array. Maybe a bug in intellisense of vs2008?

Comment: @codymanix - I believe it was a deliberate decision to hide extension methods for `IEnumerable<char>` on string instances. I can't remember the reasoning however.

Comment: @codymanix: I read somewhere (can't remember exactly where) that this was a deliberate design decision because they didn't want the full list of `IEnumerable<>` extensions popping up and cluttering intellisense whenever `string` was being used. A flawed decision, in my opinion.

Comment: @codymanix - Here's a question on SO about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345883/why-doesnt-vs-2008-display-extension-methods-in-intellisense-for-string-class

Comment: I see from the answers here that ToCharArray is not needed, so then I learned something as well :)