# Keeping namespaces for internal classes from appearing in intellisense

Tags: c#, namespaces, usability, class-library

I am writing a class library that contains classes with purely internal members. I have these divided into namespaces. There are no public or protected members in these internal classes.
The thing is, when I use this class library in a client application, these namespaces show up on intellisense. of course, they contain no accessable items, so it just ends, but I am worried that this may confuse users of the library
example:

```
    namespace mynamespace.yournamespace  
    {  
        internal class blah  
        {  
            internal void function1(){};  
            internal void function2(){};  
        }  
    }
```

When used externally intellisense will show for: mynamespace.yournamespace but not offer any members (because theyre internal).
The question then, is, is there a way to prevent those internal classes from showing up in intellisense, or am I just worried about nothing? or.....if its internal, does it even need its own namespace?
Any help appreciated

(there is a similar post at: [How can I prevent a public class that provides extension methods from appearing in Intellisense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295287/how-can-i-prevent-a-public-class-that-provides-extension-methods-from-appearing-i) that was inconclusive.)

Comment: Nothing "needs" a namespace. You can omit a namespace completely, which will put things into the "default" namespace that has no name. So whether an internal class needs a namespace is a question of best practices - the language certainly allows you not to have one.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess thats (implicitly) part of the question as well...maybe just dumping all that stuff into the root or "blank" namespace is the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think there is a way.

Based on the error

> Error 1   A namespace declaration cannot have modifiers or attributes

I don't see how you could specify that a namespace should be hidden.

The only (?) other way this might have been done is with include/exclude lists in the Intellisense settings but they're not there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`EditorBrowsableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) - it is documented to hide a member of a class defined in a different assembly, but keeps it visible if it's the same assembly. Sounds perfect for `internal` - although I haven't tried it myself.

I guess it didn't work in your linked question because it's intended for properties or methods only: "Specifies that a property or method is viewable in an editor."

Comment: I gave it a try, but it won't compile: Error A namespace declaration cannot have modifiers or attributes

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer [Custom intellisense for server controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307514/custom-intellisense-for-server-controls)